# pmlr with only the intercept

Tags: r, intercept

I am trying to perform a penalized multinomial logistic regression with R. I use the `pmlr` package, which is quite nice. Unfortunately, this code does not estimate pseudo R2. To estimate it on my own I need to perform a "only intercept" model with `plmr`. I have used the following command to do this:

```
Res <- pmlr(y~1, data=x, weights=NULL, 
      alpha=0.05, penalized = TRUE, 
      method = c("likelihood","wald")[1], joint=FALSE)
```

with function `y~1` only the intercept should be incorporated, right? 
Unfortunately, I receive the following error message:

> error in 1:m : argument of length 0"

Could someone please tell me how I am able to perform the regression analysis only with the intercept? Thanks in advance!!!

Kind regrads
S Mau